# Why doesn't my http POST request from Angular 13 to a C# Web Service work?

Tags: c#, angular, web-services

I am new to Angular and am attempting to build a simple form. I have been able to retrieve some data from my C# Web Service back end and display it on my Angular 13 front end, but now I'm trying to allow the data to be updated. Here is my form:

```
<form #policydetails="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onClickSubmit(policydetails.value)">
    <table>
      <tr><td>Title: </td><td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Title" name="Title" /></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Forename: </td><td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Forename" name="Forename" /></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Surname: </td><td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Surname" name="Surname" /></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Address 1: </td><td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Address1" name="Address1" /></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Address 2: </td><td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Address2" name="Address2" /></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Address 3: </td><td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Address3" name="Address3" /></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Address 4: </td><td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Address4" name="Address4" /></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Address 5: </td><td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Address5" name="Address5" /></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Postcode: </td><td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Postcode" name="Postcode" /></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Telephone: </td><td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Telephone" name="Telephone" /></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Telephone (Work): </td><td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Telephone_Work" name="Telephone_Work" /></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Telephone (Mobile): </td><td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Telephone_Mobile" name="Telephone_Mobile" /></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Email: </td><td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Email" name="Email" /></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Customer Survey: </td><td><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="SurveyChecked" name="SurveyChecked" /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="PolicyNumber" [(ngModel)]="PolicyNumber" /></td><td><input type="submit" value="Update"></td></tr>
    </table>
  </form>
```

When the Update button is clicked the data is sent as an object of type policyDetails, which is defined here:

```
interface policyDetails {
  PolicyNumber: string;
  Title: string;
  Forename: string;
  Surname: string;
  Address1: string;
  Address2: string;
  Address3: string;
  Address4: string;
  Address5: string;
  Postcode: string;
  Telephone: string;
  Telephone_Work: string;
  Telephone_Mobile: string;
  Email: string;
  SurveyChecked: boolean;
}
```

When the button is clicked this function is called:

```
onClickSubmit(policydetails: policyDetails) {

    const headers = { 'content-type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Accept' }

    const xmlParser: xml2js.Parser = new xml2js.Parser();

    this.http.post(Constants.API_ENDPOINT_SETPHDETAILS, JSON.stringify(policydetails), { 'headers': headers, responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(data => {
      xmlParser.parseString(data, (err, result) => {
        this.populateFields(err, result, policydetails.PolicyNumber);
      });
    });

  }
```

This should then send the data to this function in my c# Web Service:

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public PolicyHolderClass SetPolicyHolderDetails(string PolicyNumber, string Title, string Forename, string Surname, string Address1, string Address2, string Address3, string Address4, string Address5, string Postcode, string Telephone, string Telephone_Work, string Telephone_Mobile, string Email, bool SurveyChecked)
    {
        HelloWorldClass hwc = new HelloWorldClass();
        hwc.SetVehPolicyHolderDetails(PolicyNumber, Title, Forename, Surname, Address1, Address2, Address3, Address4, Address5, Postcode, Telephone, Telephone_Work, Telephone_Mobile, Email, SurveyChecked);
        return hwc.GetVehPolicyHolderDetails(PolicyNumber);
    }
```

But this function is never hit, and when I look at the Console in Chrome I can see that there is a 500 Internal Error:

```
Type System.String is not supported for deserialization of an array
```

This makes no sense because there is no array, but it's clearly a C# error so the web service is being reached. There must be something wrong with my implementation, but all the examples i've found are set up the same way. I've been struggling with this for over a week now so I could really use some help! Thanks

I've been asked to show the payload from Chrome, so here it is:

```
{"Title":["MR                  "],"Forename":["D"],"Surname":["EMO_123456  "],"Address1":["7th Floor"],"Address2":["Eaton House"],"Address3":["Coventry"],"Address4":[""],"Address5":[""],"Postcode":["CV1       "],"Telephone":["02476527800"],"Telephone_Work":[""],"Telephone_Mobile":[""],"Email":["JasonTestLocalDev@globalims.co.uk"],"SurveyChecked":false,"PolicyNumber":"123456"}
```

Comment: why do you stringify/parse the json ? You should be able to give a Javascript object in the http.post method (so removing your stringify), and same on the response. If the result is a json, Javascript already parsed it. Can you log what you receive on your subscribe, before trying to parse it ?

Comment: I'm doing the stringify because I saw it in the examples I found online. I don't receive anything on subscribe because it errors when I try to post the data.

Comment: so, can you remove the stringify and let us know what happens ?

Comment: I removed the stringify but I get the same result

Comment: Can you show what is in the request content/payload, in chrome network tab ? The server is trying to get an array, and receives a string...

Comment: I've added the payload to the question

Comment: you're saying "This makes no sense because there is no array", but in the payload, all your values are arrays. `["D"]` is an array with one element, which is a string. How do you fill `policydetails` ?

Comment: When the Update button is clicked the data entered in the form gets sent to onClickSubmit, where it gets passed into the post. I don't do anything with the data.

Comment: using your HTML, I get a correct object out of the submit, witout square barckets, when I do `console.log(policydetails)` at the begginning of onClickSubmit method. We also see in the result you actually have, your "PolicyNumber" is well formed. Can you see something different about this variable in your code ?